# How to verify UITextField text?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uitextfield

I need to make sure that the user is only entering numbers into my textfield.  I have the keyboard set to numbers, but if the user is using an external keyboard they might enter a letter.  How can I detect if any characters in my `textfield.text` are characters instead of numbers?

Thanks!

Comment: check this tutorial very nice ... http://cocoabugs.blogspot.com/2011/01/allowing-only-characters-and-numbers-in.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can choose what characters can input into the textField

```
-(BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string {

    /*  this ensures that ONLY numbers can be entered, no matter what kind of keyboard is used  */
    NSCharacterSet *myCharSet = [NSCharacterSet characterSetWithCharactersInString:@"0123456789"];

    for (int i = 0; i < [string length]; i++) {
        unichar c = [string characterAtIndex:i];
        if (![myCharSet characterIsMember:c]) {
            return NO;
        }
    }

    /*  this allows you to choose how many characters can be used in the textField  */
    NSUInteger newLength = [textField.text length] + [string length] - range.length;
    return (newLength > 7) ? NO : YES;
}
```

Comment: check this tutorial very nice ... http://cocoabugs.blogspot.com/2011/01/allowing-only-characters-and-numbers-in.html

Answer (score 1):

Whenever the user enters a key this textfield delegate will be called.

```
- (BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string
```

Inside this check whether the text contains characters. if it is do your action. like promptimg a alert or something.

Answer (score 1):

Implement `textField:shouldChangeCharactersInRange:replacementString:` in the text field's delegate and return `NO` if the passed string contains invalid characters.